# Load data in a xml file

Tags: python

I have the following text in a XML file called "sample.xml"

```
<SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
 <Word dur="0.22" stime="0.44">oh</Word>
 <Word dur="0.27" stime="1.67">bedankt</Word>
 <Word dur="0.3" stime="2.03">voor</Word>
 <Word dur="0.53" stime="2.61">deelname</Word>
</SpeechSegment>
```

I want to load the xml data so I can something similar like this:

```
raw = '''<SpeechSegment spkid="S0">
 <Word dur="0.22" stime="0.44">oh</Word>
 <Word dur="0.27" stime="1.67">bedankt</Word>
 <Word dur="0.3" stime="2.03">voor</Word>
 <Word dur="0.53" stime="2.61">deelname</Word>
</SpeechSegment>'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(raw)
result = [word.text for word in root.findall('Word')]
print result
```

But the problem is that I cant seem to load the data from an xml file. I try to do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
raw2 = ET.parse('Interview_short.xml')
```

But then this does not work:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(raw2)
result = [word.text for word in root.findall('Word')]
print result
```

Comment: "does not work" is very vague... What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

You have used different file in your `parse(**Interview_short.xml**)`. You are saying that your data is in the file `**sample.xml**`
It is working fine with following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
raw2 = ET.parse('sample.xml')
print([word.text for word in raw2.findall('Word')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs of [xml.etree.elementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) `ET.parse` and `ET.fromstring` cannot be used together for fetching the root-element of the xml.
Either you call `raw2.getroot()` on the tree returned by `ET.parse` or you provide the entire xml-string to the `ET.fromstring` method, using open for example.

Small example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
result = [word.text for word in root.findall('Word')]
print result
```